# Integrated windows authentication on linux with Asp.NET Core

Tags: active-directory, asp.net-core, windows-authentication, ntlm

Is there any chance to get the integrated windows authentication working on linux in ASP.NET Core? Is there a middleware which could enable this feature? Since its working on windows using kestrel, I thought it might not be impossible to get this working on linux.

EDIT: Is there a way to get the current windows user via NTLM?

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no middleware for this. Kestrel doesn't even support it directly, it's forwarded from IIS.